# como agregar datos a un Listview?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lista = new ListViewItem(textBox1.Text);
    lista.SubItems.Add = (textBox2.Text);
    lista.SubItems.Add = (textBox3.Text);
    listView1.Items.Add(lista);

    listView1.Items.Add(lista);
}
```

Se supone que esa es la manera correcta, pero me da un error en `lista.SubItems.Add` por que dice que no puedo agregarle "add",porque es un grupo de métodos

Answer (score 1):

`Add` no es una propiedad, sino un método. Esto significa que no puedes "asignar" un valor a add, debes ejecutar el método pasando como parámetro el item a añadir.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lista = new ListViewItem(textBox1.Text);
    lista.SubItems.Add(textBox2.Text);
    lista.SubItems.Add(textBox3.Text);
    listView1.Items.Add(lista);
}
```